# Trouble setting non-admin user's shell to fish in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, shell, fish, iterm2

*It was recommend that I post here because the fish maintainer is active on overflow.*

I am struggling to install the fish shell on OS X El Capitan.

My user structure is setup so I have an administrator account and a standard account. The standard account is the one that I use and simply have the admin account for security reasons. However, I am unable to install fish on my standard account. It is installed perfectly on my admin account, but when I change the shell from bash to fish, I get the following error in iTerm2:

> A session ended very soon after starting. Check that the command in
>   profile "my_admin_username" is correct.

In the shell, I am also receiving the following error:

```
login: /usr/local/bin/fish: Permission denied
```

Now, the above would make sense, as I am only able to use fish when `su`ing, but I have been unsuccessful thus far in setting fish up correctly to work across all of my accounts.

For what it's worth, the permissions for `/usr/local/bin/fish` are set to `755/-rwxr-xr-x`.

This is a clean, recent install so I am not sure what is causing this error. I can revert to bash easily, but I really want to be able to use fish.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I presume you added the full path to `fish` to `/etc/shells`? And went to `System Preferences->Accounts` and set the login shell there?

Comment: Setting the shell is not programming, and this is off-topic.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes. The full path to fish is in /etc/shells and the login shell is set and is what is giving the problem

Comment: Could maybe be related to new *"System Integrity Protection"* feature.

Comment: What are the permissions of the directories ~/.config and ~/.config/fish and the files contained in there?

Comment: `total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 31 badfilms  staff  1054 Oct 11 17:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x   6 badfilms  staff   204 Oct  9 20:18 fish
drwxr-xr-x   3 badfilms  staff   102 Oct  9 15:26 .`

Comment: `total 56
-rw-------  1 badfilms  staff   6274 Oct  9 20:32 fish_history
drwxr-xr-x  6 badfilms  staff    204 Oct  9 20:18 .
-rw-r--r--  1 badfilms  staff   1147 Oct  9 20:18 fishd.a0999b132783
-rw-r--r--  1 badfilms  staff     36 Oct  9 15:28 config.fish
-rw-------  1 badfilms  staff  12288 Oct  9 15:27 .config.fish.swp
drwxr-xr-x  3 badfilms  staff    102 Oct  9 15:26 ..`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have to add the path /usr/local/bin/fish to /etc/shells. Login shells are required to be present in this list as a security measure.

Comment: It is already in /etc/shells  -- I have troubleshooted the obvious things such as that already.